# How do I find the polarity of a U-shaped electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

How do I find the polarity of a U-shaped electromagnet ?

[image: U shaped solenoid]

Current flowing clockwise --> South Pole

Current flowing anticlockwise --> North Pole

However the direction of flow of current *changes when seen from top as compared to bottom*. From the examples, I find that one should view the direction from the bottom. So why is this so ?

In this image:

[image: Another solenoid]

I believe the polarity at **P is North and that at Q is South**. Am I right ?

Is there any other method to determine the **polarity of a U-shaped** electromagnet ?

Comment: I find [this mnemonic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CZfZN.png), with arrows at the points of the N and the S, more helpful for getting the polarities right without fumbling around with left- and right-hand rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current direction $I$ is from the positive terminal of the voltage source to the negative terminal.

[image]

Look end on along the axis of the electromagnet.
Clockwise current $I$ direction $\Rightarrow$ south pole
Anticlockwise current $I$ direction $\Rightarrow$ north pole

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to remember the direction of the field lines in a solenoid is to use the right hand rule:

[image: Right hand rule]

The current flows in the direction of your fingers and your thumb points towards the North pole. In the case of your U shaped solenoid just use the right hand rule at the ends of the solenoid.

[image: Another solenoid]

And you can easily see that P is indeed the North pole.

One complication in this is that you have to correctly identify which direction the current is flowing. Conventional current flows from the battery positive terminal to the battery negative terminal, so in the diagram it's flowing in the same direction as your fingers are pointing.

Answer (score -3):

Suspend a bar magnet and check how the poles align.