# How do I determine the polarity of a circular current carrying coil?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

How do I determine the **polarity at points X, Y and Z** ?

[image]

I believe that the face of the coil from which the lines of force appear to emerge is the NORTH POLE whereas the face into which they enter must be the SOUTH POLE.

Using the ***CLOCK RULE***,

x=North Pole

Y=South Pole

What would be the polarity at Z ?

Comment: This is a turn coil and what you are trying to do is liken it to a magnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a one turn coil and you are trying to liken it to a magnet.
Looking at the coil as shown in your diagram the magnetic field line are going into the coil and so that face is equivalent to a south pole.
Looking at the coil from the other side the magnetic field lines are coming out of the coil and so from that aspect the face is a north pole.

If $Z$ is in the plane of the coil then unless you state from which aspect you are looking at the coil you cannot designate a polarity.

I do not see how you can assign a polarity to regions/positions $X$ and $Y$.

[Have a look at this post.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278768/how-do-i-find-the-polarity-of-a-u-shaped-electromagnet)